# Can't show Toast inside AsyncTask inside a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I'm using a DialogFragment to show a simple form, which then is posted to a remote server and a success/fail code is sent back.

However whenever I want to show a Toast when an error occurred I get an exception in which getActivity() returns null. Any idea why this is?

This is a summary of the code:

```
private class UploadNewGroupToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{

    ProgressDialog createGroupProgressDialog;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
           public void run() 
           {
               createGroupProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
               createGroupProgressDialog.setTitle("Creating group...");
               createGroupProgressDialog.show();
           }
        });


        String encodedImage = params[0];
        String groupTitle = params[1];
        String groupDesc = params[2];

        //Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_API_CREATE_GROUP);

        try
        {
            // Add data
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            if(encodedImage != null)
            {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("picture", encodedImage));
            }
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", groupTitle));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("desc", groupDesc));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", "MY_TOKEN_HERE!"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Log.d("APP", "Going to execute ");
            final String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            Log.d("APP", "Back from execute, responseBody is " + responseBody);


            //More business logic here
            //   . . . . .

            throw new Exception(); //simulate an error

        } catch (final Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("APP", "Exception es " + e.getMessage());
            createGroupProgressDialog.dismiss();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()    //App dies here!
            {
               public void run() 
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
               }
            }); 

        }

        return null; 
    }
```

Here's the logcat:

```
11-04 00:16:18.414: E/AndroidRuntime(7229): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 00:16:18.414: E/AndroidRuntime(7229):     at com.myapp.android.GroupCreateDialogFragment$UploadNewGroupToServer.doInBackground(GroupCreateDialogFragment.java:204)
11-04 00:16:18.414: E/AndroidRuntime(7229):     at com.myapp.android.GroupCreateDialogFragment$UploadNewGroupToServer.doInBackground(GroupCreateDialogFragment.java:1)
11-04 00:16:18.414: E/AndroidRuntime(7229):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-04 00:16:18.414: E/AndroidRuntime(7229):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-04 00:16:18.414: E/AndroidRuntime(7229):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: Did you get "Log.d("APP", "Exception es " + e.getMessage());" message in your logcat.

Comment: post your logcat and where are you starting your asynchtask..

Comment: Yeah, it's unrelated to getActivity().  It says "11-04 00:13:10.124: D/FB(7229): Exception es Value <pre>Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Comment: @Sandy what is line 204 in `GroupCreateDialogFragment.java`

Comment: try to use YourActivity.this instead of getActivity()

Comment: It's `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()    //App dies here!`

Comment: @silvia_aut its in a fragment that won't work

Comment: @Sandy when you invoke asynctask use `new UploadNewGroupToServer(getActivity().execute();`. Now in the constructor `Context mContext;` and `pulic void UploadNewGroupToServer(COntext context){mContext = context;}` use mContext instead of `getActivtiy`

Comment: @Sandy getActivity() returns null when the your fragment is not attached to the activity or it is already detached from the activity then only it will be null..so check your dialogfragment and its lifecycle methods..

Comment: @Raghunandan Yeah this worked, care to make it an answer?

Comment: @Sandy sure i will and i did post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke asynctask use

```
new UploadNewGroupToServer(getActivity()).execute();.
```

Now in the constructor

```
Context mContext; 
pulic void UploadNewGroupToServer(Context context)
{
mContext = context;
}
```

Also move your progressdialog initialization to the constructor

```
pulic void UploadNewGroupToServer(Context context)
{
 createGroupProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
 createGroupProgressDialog.setTitle("Creating group..."); 
}
```

In `onPreExecute`

```
public void onPreExecute()
{
     super.onPreExecute();
     createGroupProgressDialog.show();
}
```

Also instead of displaying toast in `doInbackground` return result and in `onPostExecute` dismiss dialog and show toast accordingly.

Comment: This worked, but using FragmentActivity instead of Context. Thanks @Raghunandan

Comment: I didn't copy/paste, but used your recommendation to create a FragmentActivity object in the constructor and referencing that, instead of getActivity(). This worked even in `doInBackground`.

Comment: Is it considered a bad practice to show Toasts in `doInBackground`?

Comment: @Sandy doInbackground is invoked on the background thread. so your network related operations should be there. onPostExecute is invoked on the ui thread so update ui there. just keep things in order. it is easy to debug and also easier to code. why use `runOnUithread` in doInbackground when you can update ui in onPostExecute right?. Instead of asynctask you can use threads also just that asynctask makes it easier

Comment: Oh ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks again @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

Could your create a handler in your async task? If handler created in UI thread(If use MainLooper) post method samely runOnUiThread.

```
private class UploadNewGroupToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{

    ProgressDialog createGroupProgressDialog;
    Handler handler;    


    protected void onPreExecute(){
      handler = new Handler();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {

        handler.post(new Runnable() 
        {
           public void run() 
           {
               createGroupProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
               createGroupProgressDialog.setTitle("Creating group...");
               createGroupProgressDialog.show();
           }
        });


        String encodedImage = params[0];
        String groupTitle = params[1];
        String groupDesc = params[2];

        //Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_API_CREATE_GROUP);

        try
        {
            // Add data
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            if(encodedImage != null)
            {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("picture", encodedImage));
            }
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", groupTitle));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("desc", groupDesc));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", "MY_TOKEN_HERE!"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Log.d("APP", "Going to execute ");
            final String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            Log.d("APP", "Back from execute, responseBody is " + responseBody);


            //More business logic here
            //   . . . . .

            throw new Exception(); //simulate an error

        } catch (final Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("APP", "Exception es " + e.getMessage());
            createGroupProgressDialog.dismiss();

            handler.post(new Runnable()    //App dies here!
            {
               public void run() 
               {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
               }
            }); 

        }

        return null; 
    }
```